# Odd Behaviour of Loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, scope

I am writing a script to report statistics from a text file in Markdown. The file contains book titles and dates. Each date belongs to the titles that follow, until a new date appears.  Here is a sample:

```
#### 8/23/05
Defining the World (Hitchings)  
#### 8/26/05
Lost Japan  
#### 9/5/05
The Kite Runner  
*The Dark Valley (Brendon)*  
#### 9/9/05
Active Liberty
```

I iterate over lines in the file with a `for` loop and examine each line to see if it's a date.  If it's a date, I set a variable `this_date`.  If it's a title, I make it into a dict with the current value of `this_date`.

There are two exceptions: the file starts with titles, not a date, so I set an initial value for `this_date` before the for loop.  And halfway through the file there is a region where dates were lost, and I set a specific date for those titles.

But in the resulting list of dicts, all the titles are given that date until the lost-data region starts.  After that point, the rest of the titles are given the date that appears last in the file.  What is most confusing: when I print the contents of `this_date` right before appending the new dict, it contains the correct value on every loop.

I expect `this_date` to be visible at all levels of the loop.  I know I need to break this up into functions, and passing results explicitly between functions will probably fix the issue, but I'd like to know why this approach didn't work.  Thank you very much.

```
result = []

# regex patterns
ddp = re.compile('\d+') # extract digits
mp = re.compile('^#+\s*\d+') # captures hashes and spaces
dp = re.compile('/\d+/') # captures slashes
yp = re.compile('\d+$')
sp = re.compile('^\*')

# initialize
this_date = {
    'month': 4,
    'day': 30,
    'year': 2005
}
# print('this_date initialized')

for line in text:
    if line == '':
        pass
    else:
        if '#' in line: # markdown header format - line is a new date
            if 'Reconstructing lost data' in line: # handle exception
            # titles after this line are given 12/31/14 (the last date in the file) instead of 8/31/10
            # all prior dates are overwritten with 8/31/10
            # but the intent is that titles after this line appears have date 8/31/10, until the next date
                this_date = {
                    'month': 8,
                    'day': 31,
                    'year': 2010
                }
                # print('set this_date to handle exception')
            else: # get the date from the header
                month = ddp.search( mp.search(line).group() ) # digits only
                day = ddp.search( dp.search(line).group() ) # digits only
                year = yp.search(line)
                if month and day and year:
                    # print('setting this_date within header parse')
                    this_date['month'] = int(month.group())
                    this_date['day'] = int(day.group())
                    this_date['year'] = ( int(year.group()) + 2000 )
                else:
                    pass
        else: # line is a title
            x = {
                'date': this_date,
                'read': False
                }
            if sp.match(line):  # starts with asterisk - has been read
                x['read'] = True
                x['title'] = line[1:-3] # trim trailing asterisk and spaces
            else:
                x['title'] = line
            # this_date is correct when printed here
            # print('this_date is ' + str(this_date['month']) + '/' + str(this_date['day']) + '/' + str(this_date['year']) )
            result.append(x)
            # x has correct date when printed here
            # print(x)

# print("Done; found %d titles.") % len(result)
# elements of result have wrong dates (either 8/31/10 or 12/31/14, no other values) when printed here
# print( result[0::20])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the `this_date` dictionary *just once*. You then *reuse* that dictionary each loop iteration. You are only adding *references* to that dictionary to your `result` list; it is just the *one* dictionary referenced over and over again.

Store a *new* copy of the dictionary each loop iteration:

```
x = {
    'date': this_date.copy(),
    'read': False
    }
```

Your code could do with some simplification; I'd use [`datetime.date()` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) here instead as they model dates properly. No regular expressions are required:

```
from datetime import datetime

current_date = None
results = []
for line in text:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue

    if line.startswith('#'):
        current_date = datetime.strptime(line.strip('# '), '%m/%d/%y').date()
        continue

    entry = {'date': current_date, 'read': False}

    if line.startswith('*') and line.endswith('*'):
        # previously read
        line = line.strip('*')
        entry['read'] = True

    entry['title'] = line
    results.append(entry)
```

Because `datetime.date()` objects are immutable and we create a new `date` object each time we encounter a header line, you can safely re-use the last-read date.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> text = '''\
... #### 8/23/05
... Defining the World (Hitchings)  
... #### 8/26/05
... Lost Japan  
... #### 9/5/05
... The Kite Runner  
... *The Dark Valley (Brendon)*  
... #### 9/9/05
... Active Liberty 
... '''.splitlines(True)
>>> current_date = None
>>> results = []
>>> for line in text:
...     line = line.strip()
...     if not line:
...         continue
...     if line.startswith('#'):
...         current_date = datetime.strptime(line.strip('# '), '%m/%d/%y').date()
...         continue
...     entry = {'date': current_date, 'read': False}
...     if line.startswith('*') and line.endswith('*'):
...         # previously read
...         line = line.strip('*')
...         entry['read'] = True
...     entry['title'] = line
...     results.append(entry)
... 
>>> pprint(results)
[{'date': datetime.date(2005, 8, 23),
  'read': False,
  'title': 'Defining the World (Hitchings)'},
 {'date': datetime.date(2005, 8, 26), 'read': False, 'title': 'Lost Japan'},
 {'date': datetime.date(2005, 9, 5),
  'read': False,
  'title': 'The Kite Runner'},
 {'date': datetime.date(2005, 9, 5),
  'read': True,
  'title': 'The Dark Valley (Brendon)'},
 {'date': datetime.date(2005, 9, 9), 'read': False, 'title': 'Active Liberty'}]
```

Comment: Alternatively, create a new dict instead of modifying the old one. Then there's no need to copy it hundreds of times.

Comment: @Rawing: the OP mentioned they expect the date to be reused in subsequent iterations.

Comment: Both approaches worked.  What is tradeoff between inserting a copy of the dict 'date': this_date.copy()
and creating a new dict
'date': {
    'month': this_date['month'],
    'day': this_date['day'],
    'year': this_date['year']
}

Comment: @user2014160: creating a new dictionary with manually copying is just more typing work. Using `dict.copy()` to create a shallow copy produces the exact same result without you having to be so verbose.

Comment: I didn't understand @Rawing's instruction then... so much to learn.  Thanks both!

Comment: Yup, datetime is better.  Thanks again.